# OSX: "last" command and utmpx

Tags: macos

We have a bunch of OSX Yosemite machines.  I can go to any of them and issue the `last` command and see possibly a year of records.  I know that OSX went to using utmpx years ago but I don't think `last` uses that facility under the hood.  I can see the utmpx file for a given machine in `/var/run` (`/private/var/run/`) but each one is tiny.

I have a simple C program that reads the local utmpx file (`getutxent`) but only see a couple of records, justifying the small size of the file.  I think I know that the utmpx system is not "started" until the utmpx file exists so it is possible that my exploration created the now tiny files.

What resource is the OSX `last` command reading from?

What is the current state of the art for getting machine usage data off of Macs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) Apple has replaced the `utmp`/`wtmp` mechanism with the Apple logging system. See `man 5 utmpx` for details.  Here is a pertinent excerpt:

```
Traditionally, separate files would be used to store the running log of the logins
and logouts (wtmpx), and the last login of each user (lastlogx).  With the avail-
ability of the Apple system log facility asl(3), these separate files can be
replace with log entries, which are automatically generated when utmpx entries are
written.  The API to access the logins and logouts is described in
endutxent_wtmp(3) while the last login info is accessible with getlastlogx(3).
```

See `man asl` for the programatic interface to the log system.  Apple Syslog saves all its utmp/wtmp/lastlog-like information in /var/log/asl/*.